# Tablet termux node-red-node-serialport launch problem

Tags: android, node-red, node-serialport, termux

I have this problem and would be very happy if somebody helped me figure this out:

#### What are you trying to do?

Install node-red-node-serialport to node-red running on ARMv8 Exynos 7870 SM-T580 Samsung tablet using termux

#### What happens?

> WARNING: linker:
>   /data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib/node_modules/node-red-node-serialport/node_modules/@serialport/bindings/build/Release/bindings.node
>   has text relocations. This is wasting memory and prevents security
>   hardening. Please fix.
>
> [warn] [node-red-node-serialport/serialport] Error: dlopen failed:
>   cannot locate symbol "_Z22linuxSetCustomBaudRateij" referenced by
>   "/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib/node_modules/node-red-node-serialport/node_modules/@serialport/bindings/build/Release/binding.node"...

#### What should have happened?

Start node-red-node-serialport without these errors

#### Code to Reproduce the Issue

```
tsudo node /data/data/com.termux/files/usr/bin/node-red
```

#### Versions, Operating System and Hardware

- SerialPort@? node-red-node-serialport@0.7.1 and serialport@7.1.4
- Node.js v? v11.10.1
- Windows? Linux? Mac? Android
- Hardware and chipset? (Prolific/FTDI/Other) Planning to use FTDI but don't get that far now

Comment: I very much doubt that the native code in the serialport (used by the node-red-serialport node) will build on Android.

Answer (score 0):

The docs for the serialport node does not list Android as a supported platform in it's [README.md](https://github.com/node-serialport/node-serialport#bindings) so I very much doubt you will be able to get this to work.

The only listed supported platgforms are Linux/Mac/Windows

The full list of supported platforms is here:https://serialport.io/docs/en/guide-platform-support

It does not include Android or Termux